# creating MongoDB Replicaset on windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, replicaset

when creating MongoDB ReplicaSet on 2 windows Servers what ports should be open?
Just port 22 is enough?
I have not telnet from one server to the other one on port 22 and 23.
which other conditions should be met to create ReplicaSet on 2 Windows machines?

Comment: Port 22 is reserved for SSH and most likely already in use. Use the default port 27017/tcp, actually there is no reason to use any other unless you deploy a test with all services on one host.

Comment: The database is already installed and configured on Port 17017 by default on both servers. Which port is used to ship the Oplog contents to secondaries? isn't it Port 22? I haven't configured Replica Set on Windows and am familiar with conditions.

Comment: No, MongoDB uses only the one port you configured, i.e. port 17017 is used for both, for replication and also for client connections.

Comment: thank you so much, after opening port 27017 on both servers I could create the replica set